# Автоматическое обновление с PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play

Приветствую, меня интересует, как сделать так, чтобы приложение автоматически обновлялось с PlayStore, когда будет загружена новая версия.

Как можно такое организовать ?

Comment: Так автоматически же происходит.

Comment: Я просто ни разу не пробовал. А нужно ли для этого что то прописывать в Gradle или в Manifest ?

Comment: Нет, просто публикуете новую версию, и у всех пользователей у которых установленно ваше приложение и включено автообновление приложение обновится автоматически. Ну только перед публикацией надо повысить versionCode что бы гугл принял новую версию.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ !